# Is that a local module the same as an $E_2$ module?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ct.category-theory

Let $A$ be an $E_2$ algebra in a braided monoidal category $C$, i.e. a commutative monoid in $C$. Denote the braiding by $c_{x,y}$ for objects $x,y\in C$. We define a local module over $A$ as follows:

A left $A$-module $(M,\rho)$ is called *local* if $\rho\circ c_{M,A}\circ c_{A,M}=\rho$.

Question: Is this an $E_2$-module over the $E_2$-algebra $A$?

What I know is the basic definition of an $E_n$-algebra by operad. And I have a geometric intuition of an $E_2$-module. But I never see a rigorous proof of the above question (if it is true). I hope someone can provide a rigorous argument from the language of operads to the language of ordinary module theory.

Moreover, for an $E_1$-algebra $A'$ in a braided monoidal category $C$, we can always define a local module for $A'$ since we have braiding. Even though there is no canonical braiding and monoidal structure on the category $C_{A'}^{loc}$ of local modules over $A$. So, if local modules are $E_2$ modules in some sense, is it reasonable to say an $E_2$-module over an $E_1$-algebra?